# Is it better to declare variables in C before passing them to a function?

Tags: c, struct, constructor

Or does it not matter?

I'm learning C and getting to grips with structs. I've tried to emulate a basic "constructor" method in C by passing string values to a method, creating a new struct object, and returning it from the function. I've realised that there are several permissible ways of doing this:

1. Create a struct object directly, without offloading to a method.
2. Declaring all of the member variables for my struct object, then passing it to a 'constructor' method
3. Directly passing the values I want to populate my object with into a 'constructor' method and storing the result in a struct object.
4. Create and use a struct object using my 'constructor' method in one line, without storing it.

Here's my code, and you'll see what I mean:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Book {
    char title[50];
    char author[50];
    int pageCount;
};

void printBook(struct Book _book) {
    printf("%s by %s is %d pages long.\n", _book.title, _book.author, _book.pageCount);
}

struct Book createBook(char *title, char *author, int pageCount) {
    struct Book newBook;
    strcpy(newBook.title, title);
    strcpy(newBook.author, author);
    newBook.pageCount = pageCount;
    return newBook;
}

int main() {
    // 1. Create a struct object directly.
    struct Book hp1;
    strcpy(hp1.title, "Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone");
    strcpy(hp1.author, "J. K. Rowling");
    hp1.pageCount = 223;
    printBook(hp1);
    
    // 2. Declare the member variables, then pass to a 'constructor' method.
    char t2[] = "A Game of Thrones";
    char a2[] = "George R. R. Martin";
    int pc2 = 687;    
    struct Book got1 = createBook(t2, a2, pc2);
    printBook(got1);
    
    // 3. Directly pass the member data to the 'constructor' method.
    struct Book ag = createBook("American Gods", "Neil Gaiman", 465);
    printBook(ag);
    
    // 4. Create a new object instance without storing it.
    printBook(createBook("Coraline", "Neil Gaiman", 186));
    return 0;
}
```

My question is, what are the advantages and disadvantages of these different methods? I understand that method 4 is obviously not sensible if you want to re-use the object, but is it suitable for a one-off? Are there any hidden costs associated with passing a string value to a function without storing it in a variable first (method 3), or is this always going to be more performant than storing it first (method 2)?

Comment: Method 1 is awkward as you can see by yourself. Method 2 is pretty pointless, rather use method 3 instead. Method 4 really depends on your use case, it's perfectly valid if you don't need to store it, but on the other hand how will the book be destroyed??

Comment: Best is probaly method 3, it's obviously the simplest and most readable version, but anyway, you might need to call `deleteBook(ag)` once you're done with the book, depending on what `createBook` does (like allocating memory).

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware that you needed to delete structures as well. From googling that should amount to one line `delete [bookObject];`, correct?

Comment: no `delete [bookObject]` is not C (nor C++ BTW). For deleting you need to write you own functon, but in your case there is no need for a deleter function because `createBook` doesn't allocate any memory (or other things that need to be undone)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should note that this function will cause undefined behavior if you pass strings which are longer than 50 bytes.

You should use `strncpy` in this case and ensure that the `0-byte` is at the end of the array.

```
struct Book createBook(char *title, char *author, int pageCount)
{
    struct Book newBook;
    strncpy(newBook.title, title, sizeof(title));
    strncpy(newBook.author, author, sizeof(author));
    newBook.title[49] = 0;   // Truncate the string if it was too long
    newBook.author[49] = 0;
    newBook.pageCount = pageCount;
    return newBook;
}
```

Case 1 is not really a "Constructor" because you simply initialize it where you need it.

Case 2 is wasting stackspace, because you create a copy of the data on the stack, then pass it on to create yet another copy on the stack, and pass it back which will also create a copy on the stack. And you have the values already in your struct afterwards, so I would refer to those insead of the variables, which are no longer needed.

Case 3+4 are basically the same, and is the best approach. If you don't need the local object again, only for the purpose of calling the method, then you don't need to keep a copy hanging around.

You should be aware though, that especially for larger structs, copying the object around by value is very ineffientc, so you might have to consider allocating the object dynamically and freeing it when you are done. Since `C` doesn't provide a destructor mechanism, like `C++` does, you have to do it for yourself though.

The way you implemented your "constructor" doesn't require any deallocation though.

Comment: Thank you! Can you clarify what and why "undefined behaviour" happens if the string is longer than 50 bytes though? Can't C char arrays hold more than 50 bytes? I'm also confused because you say bytes, but you've set the 50th character of the char array to a null character (at least, I think so.) Otherwise I've accepted the answer as it answers my main question perfectly, I just don't understand those details :)

Comment: It can't hold more than 50 characters, because you said in your declaration that the array can hold only 50 character `char title[50];`. Since a c-string needs a `0-Byte` it can only have 49 characters because it needs one character for that as well. If you now copy a string with 200 characters your stack gets overwritten and the programm may crash.

Comment: Ah... that's incredibly stupid of me, I forgot that I instantiated my array with explicit bounds. Your answer makes perfect sense now - just give me a moment to remove the egg from my face :)